# Why is `($ 4) (> 3)` equivalent to `4 > 3`?

Tags: haskell

I noticed as I was playing around with Haskell today that it is possible to do something like

```
($ 4) (> 3)
```

which yields `True`. What is going on here? It'd be great to have some intuition.

My guess? It looks like the `($ 4)` is an incomplete function application, but where I'm confused is that `$` is an infix operator, so shouldn't it look like `(4 $)`? This doesn't compile, so clearly not, which leads me to believe that I don't really understand what's going on. The `(>3)` term makes sense to me, because if you supply something like `(\x -> x 4) (>3)`, you end up with the same result.

Comment: The answers are excellent, but I'd like add that `(\`op\` e)` is syntactic sugar for `(\x -> x \`op\` e)` and `(e \`op\`)` for `(\x -> e \`op\` x)`, where `\`op\`` is operator (either normal one such as `+`, `-` etc, or function in backticks).

Comment: read `(f $)` as "_call the_ function f" ; read `($ 4)` as "_call with_ 4 as argument". "Call with 4" "is greater than 3?" is "Is 4 greater than 3?". `($ 4) (> 3) == (> 3) 4 == 4 > 3 == (4 >) 3`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`($ 4)` is what's called a [section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator). It's a way of partially applying an infix operator, but providing the right-hand side instead of the left. It's exactly equivalent to `(flip ($) 4)`.

Similarly, (> 3) is a section.

```
($ 4) (> 3)
```

can be rewritten as

```
(flip ($) 4) (> 3)
```

which is the same as

```
flip ($) 4 (> 3)
```

which is the same as

```
(> 3) $ 4
```

And at this point, it should be clear that this boils down to `(4 > 3)`.

Comment: @apc: In case you're not too familiar with partial application, notice that the type signature `add :: Int -> Int -> Int` can be written more explicitly as `add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)`, i.e. "add is a function taking an `Int` and returning a function `Int -> Int`. Also google "currying haskell".

Comment: Thanks @jberryman. I actually did know that, but it's a good thing you mentioned it for other noobs. :)

Comment: @apc: I just wanted to also point out that `(> 3)` is also a section and you resolve it the exact same way you resolve `($ 4)`.

Answer (score 12):

You can partially apply an infix operator from either side. For commutative operators such as `+`, it doesn't matter if you say `(+ 1)` or `(1 +)`, but for example for division you can supply either the dividend `(5 /)` or the divisor `(/ 5)`.

The function application operator takes a function as the left-hand operand and a parameter as the right-hand operand (`f $ x`), so you can partially apply it either with a function `(f $)` or with a parameter `($ x)`. So given

```
($ 4) (> 3)
```

You first partially apply the $-operator with the parameter `4` and supply it with the function `(> 3)`. So what this essentially becomes is

```
(> 3) $ 4
```

Which is the same as `(4 > 3)`.

Answer (score 6):

`($ 4)` is the function that takes a function and applies `4` to it.

`(> 3)` is the function that takes a number and checks if it is greater than 3.

So by giving the latter function to the former, you are essentially applying `4` to the function that checks if its input is greater than `3`, and thus you get `True`.